# How to get public_content like media at location in Instagram API?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I am implementing Instagram API in my iOS App.I need public_content from these end points

1. https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS_Token
2. https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag-name/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Do I need to authenticate user to get these info ? If so what are the scopes ?
Can I get these info without Authentication of user ?

Comment: you cannot get approval for this API anymore

Comment: @krisrak what do you mean? I'm trying call `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, but docs say I need `public_content` also. Apps like tinder currently get photos for users profile, id like to do the same.

Comment: you can get access to /users/self/media recent API without public_content, but you cannot get tags and location API access, u can only get photos of logged in user

Comment: Well, no luck with it? We can't get media by location?